# Porque meu site está lento?

Tags: aplicação-web, servidor, carregamento

Boa tarde, eu estou detectando lentidões extremas no meu site logo na inicialização da página. Conforme demonstrado nessa imagem, existe uma espera muito grande antes que o restante do conteúdo comece a ser carregado. Eu carreguei essa url no pingdom mas a home também apresenta a mesma anomalia.

Quais motivos podem levar a uma espera tão grande antes mesmo de começar a carregar o conteúdo? Servidor, falta de recursos, excesso de uso de recursos da hospedagem ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem ver o código fica relativamente difícil dar qualquer diagnóstico...

Comment: Você pode usar o PageSpeed para ter uma base...